# Uniqueness is a consequence of a non-vanishing autonomous flux

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f: \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ continuous and $f(x)\ne 0$, or all $x\in\mathbb R$. Let also $\varphi,\psi : \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, continuously differentiable functions satisfying
$$
\varphi'(t)=f\big(\varphi(t)\big),\quad \psi'(t)=f\big(\psi(t)\big),
$$
for all $t\in\mathbb R$. Show that there exists a $\tau\in\mathbb R$, such that
$$
\psi(t)=\varphi(t-\tau),\quad \text{for all $t\in\mathbb R$}.
$$

**Note.** Here uniqueness is the question, but in order to even consider proving it, one has to first make sure that the ranges of the two solutions intersect!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just proves that the ranges must overlap. In fact, 
the range of $\phi$ and $\psi$ is $\mathbb{R}$.

Without loss of generality, we may take $f$ to be positive everywhere. Hence both $\phi,\psi$ are strictly increasing.

Let $\psi_\infty = \lim_{t \uparrow \infty} \psi(t)$, and suppose $\psi_\infty < \infty$.
 Let $\psi_\infty = \lim_{t \uparrow \infty} \psi(t)$. Since $f$ is continuous, we must have $f(\psi_\infty) = \lim_{t \uparrow \infty} f(\psi(t))$. Since $f(\psi_\infty)>0$, we must have $\lim_{t \uparrow \infty} \psi(t) = \infty$, a contradiction. Hence $\psi_\infty = \infty$.

The other limits follow in exactly the same fashion.

Uniqueness was more straightforward that I thought. It follows from the fact that $f(x) \neq 0$:

Suppose $x_0 = \phi(t_0) $. Let $g(x) = \int_{x_o}^x { dy \over f(y) }$. Note that $g(x_0) = 0$ and $g'(x) = {1 \over f(x) } \ne 0$. The inverse function theorem gives the existence of a function $\gamma$ defined on a neighbourhood $U$ of $0$ such that $\gamma(g(x)) = x$ for $x \in V$, where $V$ is some neighbourhood of $x_0$.
Now consider $f(t) = g(\phi(t))$. Then $f(t_0) = 0$, and $f'(t) = g'(\phi(t)) \phi'(t) = 1$, and so $f(t) = t-t_0$. Hence for $t-t_0 \in U$ we have $\gamma(f(t)) =\gamma(t-t_0) = \phi(t)$.

Suppose $\psi$ is another solution that passes through $(t_0, x_0)$, then the
same considerations show that $\psi(t) = \gamma(t-t_0) = \phi(t)$, for $t-t_0 \in U$.

Let $T\subset \mathbb{R}$ be the points at which two continuous solutions match. This set is closed by continuity, and open by the above reasoning, hence since $\mathbb{R}$ is connected either $T$ is empty or the whole space.

Since the ranges of $\phi, \psi$ overlap, there are points $t_0,t_1$ such that $\phi(t_0) = \psi(t_1)$. Since the system is time invariant, if $\phi$ is a solution, then so is $t \mapsto \phi(t-s)$ for any fixed $s$. Hence $t \mapsto \phi(t+t_0)$ and $t \mapsto \psi(t+t_1)$ are both solutions that pass through the point $(0,\phi(t_0)) = (0,\psi(t_1))$. Consequently $\phi(t+t_0)=\psi(t+t_1)$ for all $t$, from which we get $\psi(t) = \phi(t+t_0-t_1)$ for all $t$.

Comment: I added a uniqueness proof.